# What flavors work well within a splenda-sweetened strawberry-rhubarb cobbler?

Tags: pairing, strawberries, rhubarb

Cobbler filling is simple - strawberries, rhubarb, splenda (sucralose) and some orange zest. Are there any other spices or ingredients that would work well with the artificial sweetener and amplify or compliment the flavors?

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question (I just use sugar) but does splenda actually have a flavor besides sweetness that you'd have to take into account? Surely you're just asking what would work well with strawberries and rhubarb.

Comment: @jefromi- yes. It tastes like personified horror. Like the terror of imminent death gripping the back of your tongue as it whispers its bitter lies to your subconscious. I don't like artificial sweeteners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic flavour pairing with rhubarb is vanilla: rhubarb and vanilla custard is a British staple. Fresh custard (Creme Anglaise, as the French call it) is easy to make and delicious.

Almond also pairs well with rhubarb. You could incorporate ground almonds into the cobbler mix, or perhaps fold some amaretto liqueur into lightly whipped cream to serve with the cobbler.

As Splenda has no real flavour, just a sweet taste, both of these will work with it easily.

Answer (score 0):

cardamom and/or clove wouldn't compete with the citrus as, say, nutmeg or cinnamon. Just adds a bit of coolness and perfume.